# Why can't I connect to this WDSL in Apigee

Tags: javascript, web-services, proxy, wsdl, apigee

I need to connect to:

https://www.webselfstorage.com/webservices/externaldataaccessservice.asmx?WSDL

through Apigee to create a REST to SOAP to REST proxy.

I keep getting a box that pops up when I "fetch" the WSDL that reads "Server Error. Internal Error".

What Am I doing wrong here? The webservices documentation came with a username and password but there isn't a place to enter these on apigee so I have to wonder if that might be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Disclosure: I work at Apigee.

The internal error message is a problem in how we are displaying an error message when we run into a problem reading the WSDL and should be fixed in the future.

The reason it's having a problem reading your WSDL is because of this line, which exists several times in the WSDL:

```
                  <s:element ref="s:schema" />
```

I'm no XML expert, so what does that mean? There is a schema that contains an element that is in turn also schema? My head hurts. :)

Do you have any control over the WSDL, or is that a 3rd party WSDL that you can't modify?

I saved a copy of the file and made the following changes to get it to work. I added a line after the schema definition:

```
<s:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://www.webselfstorage.com/WebServices/ExternalDataServices">
    <s:element name="schema" type="s:schema"/>
```

Then changed the s:schema refs to:

```
                  <s:element ref="tns:schema" />
```

And the fetch worked...

I'll try to follow up with more details, but just wanted to give you an update of what I've found so far.